# Show recently modified items from 21 lists across 21 subsites in Homepage - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I need to show the 5 recently modified list items, across 21 sites and 21 lists in the same site collection in SharePoint online.

I need to only show the list item based on certain choice field column value. (Eg: Selected choice is red across all 21 lists)

I tried using Highlighted content webpart, however it shows only document libraries.

Any technical advice on which is the best possible way to show the top 5 list items would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate using something like a Content Query Web Part (CQWP) and configure a search query to find the most recently modified items.

Or you could make e.g. a wiki web part page and add 21x web parts, one for each list.  Then on all 21 lists you'd need to create a view which sorts by the Modified Date.

- Make the view **sort by** descending (so the most recently modified show at the top)
- Then set the **item limit** in the view to 5.
- On your wiki page, make sure that the view the web part uses is the new view you've made, since it will probably use the list default view initially.

[image: item limit]

### Additional Info

BTW - I'm using SP 2013, so it's possible there might be some features in SPO that I don't know about.

1. You might need to make the wiki web part page at the 'root site' in your site collection, in order for it to allow you to select data from the sub-sites.
2. Link on using [web parts in Sharepoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0).

Answer (score 0):

Tried using CQWP, but the choice field its not picking it up from 21 lists.

I cant use the view because i need to show the result in a single webpart for 21 lists from 21 subsites

Comment: I believe you would need to create 21 CQWPs - one query per list.  If memory serves correct, it shows a single field as the result - do you could select the Name or Title field.  The wiki page & web parts is more flexible for what you're looking to do; it would still need 21x web parts though